# qemu - Need read/write rights on statedir /var/lib/swtpm-localca for user tss

Tags: qemu, tpm, windows-11

I've installed swtpm and added it to a virtual machine using virt-manager (qemu+virsh).

When I'm going to start the machine, a error arises and points to a log file.

The file states:

```
Need read/write rights on statedir /var/lib/swtpm-localca for user tss.`
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach I've found is to just give the ownership of that particular folder to that user.

```
sudo chown -R tss:root /var/lib/swtpm-localca
```

On my system it has previously stated:

```
sudo ls -lach /var/lib/swtpm-localca
total 8,0K
drwxr-x---  2 swtpm root 4,0K Mär 17 11:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 80 root  root 4,0K Mär 17 11:51 ..
```

I do not know what I do break when revoking the user `swtmp` the access to that folder, but until now it works just smoothly.